# Lorentz transformation of a Weyl Spinor?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, representation-theory, lorentz-symmetry, spinors

A left handed Weyl Spinor belongs to the $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ representation of the Lorentz group. So given the Spinor, the unitary representation of the Lorentz transformation should look like $\exp{iA\cdot\theta}$ where $A=(J+iK)/2$.

Does this mean that for a Weyl Spinor, you cannot make a rotation without simultaneously making a boost?

Comment: Are you asking what a pure rotation of a Weyl spinor amounts to?

Comment: I guess I'm asking whether or not it is possible to make a pure rotation or a pure boost.

Comment: Yes, I would like the spinor to remain left handed

Comment: Your final sentence is quite confusing. Can you explain more clearly why you concluded that?

Comment: You can fake a rotation by a boost on a Weyl spinor, but on the independent spinor you must fake the same rotation by the opposite boost: is *this* what you are asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer already explains how it works correctly. I will try to point out where I think your misconception was.

I think you were saying that since $A = (J+ i K)/2$, if one wants to make a rotation, that comes necessarily with a boost. The thing is: I it's not true that left handed Weyl spinors transform only with $A$. In *every* representation we are completely free to act with all generators. Which in your basis would also contain $B = (J - i K)/2$. So rotations are those where the angles for $A$ and $B$ are the same.

I have an intuition as to why you had this misconception. Normally one presents the Lorentz algebra as being $\mathfrak{sl}(2)\oplus\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ by showing that one can redefine the generators $M_{\mu\nu}$ as follows
$$
J_i = \epsilon_{ijk} M_{jk}\,,\qquad K_i = M_{0i}\,.
$$
Then further define
$$
A_i = \frac{J_i + i K_i}{2}\,,\qquad B_i = \frac{J_i - iK_i}{2}\,.
$$
The algebra generated by $A$ and $B$ is the direct sum of two decoupled $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$
$$
[A_i,A_j] = i \,\varepsilon_{ijk} A_k\,,\qquad
[B_i,B_j] = i \,\varepsilon_{ijk} B_k\,,\qquad
[A_i,B_j] =0\,.
$$
Then the generators $A$ are interpreted as the *left*-handed ones and the generators $B$ are interpreted as the *right*-handed ones because under the action of parity $P$ one has
$$
PAP = B\,,\qquad PBP = A\,.
$$
In the same way as left- and right-handed things are swapped under parity.${}^1$

All this is true, but it absolutely does not mean that left-handed objects transform with $A_i$ and right-handed objects with $B_i$. It rather says that, if $A$ and $B$ were to transform, then they would be respectively left- and right-handed.

I expressed this maybe too verbosely, but hopefully that was the confusion and now the point is clear.

---

$\quad{}^1$In more mathematical terms we can say the following: the *adjoint* representation of the Lorentz group (i.e. the action of the Lorentz group on its own generators) is reducible and it is $(2,0)\oplus(0,2)$. It is indeed chiral, the first component is entirely left-handed and has the $A_i$ as a basis, while the second component is right-handed and has the $B_i$ as a basis.

Comment: Yes this was exactly my confusion, I appreciate you clearing it up for me!

Answer (score 1):

In the [Weyl basis of  γ-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) the  commutativity of the generator of pure rotations on spinors with $\gamma_5$ is manifest.

That is, the respective 4×4 matrices are
$$
\gamma^5= -\sigma_3\otimes \mathbb{1}\\ 
\gamma^0= \sigma_1\otimes \mathbb{1}\\ 
\gamma^k= i\sigma_2\otimes \sigma^k, 
$$
the very first being diagonal, so spinors with vanishing two-lower    components denote a $\psi_L$ Weyl spinor, and with vanishing 2-upper a $\psi_R$ spinor.

An infinitesimal pure rotation around the *l* axis of *any spinor* amounts to an increment gotten by multiplying the spinor by  $\epsilon ^{ljk}[\gamma^j,\gamma^k]\propto \mathbb{1}\otimes \sigma^l, $ also block diagonal!

So a pure rotation treats $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$ identically, and of course, cannot mix them, since the above commutator commutes with $\gamma^5$ to keep  $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$ separate and equal. In the Weyl basis this is self-evident.

Repeating the same exercise for a pure boost, your confirm that  $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$ are treated equally but oppositely.  Your would expect, this, of course, since opposite values of the boosts amount to rotations on the  respective disjoint spinor subspaces.